# What exact wireless chip does Pi 4 use?

Tags: pi-4, firmware

I will receive my Pi 4 soon, so I started breaking down image generation scripts as I like to make image myself (as I install system on computer same way, by hand).

As I want to copy just specific firmware for wireless chip without installing whole firmware-brcm80211 package from non-free part, I need to know exact exact model.

Alternatively, kernel logs should show which firmware is loaded using something like:

```
sudo journalctl -b | grep brcmfmac
```

Sorry for my english, as I don't know it so well, so some phrases may look strange.

Comment: you should realy download an image of Raspbberry Pi OS and run it before you do any modification to the image ... that will ensure that you are starting with correctly functioning hardware ... collect all required info after you boot the stock image to make sure that there is no hardware difference from the current info .... of course, getting all scripts ready before you get your board is a good thing to do

Comment: jsotola, while there should be no difference, it is good advice to check that everything is working before doing own modifications. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked for the output of `sudo journalctl -b | grep brcmfmac`. Here is it:

```
Oct 25 14:42:57 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
Oct 25 14:42:57 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
Oct 25 14:42:57 raspberrypi kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
Oct 25 14:42:57 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.txt failed with error -2
Oct 25 14:42:58 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
Oct 25 14:42:58 raspberrypi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Mar 23 2020 02:19:54 version 7.45.206 (r725000 CY) FWID 01-88ee44ea
```

And this is my Raspberry Pi model:

```
rpi ~$ cat /proc/device-tree/model
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2
```

I hope the info about WiFi chip **BCM4345/6** is sufficient.

Comment: It is exactly what I need. Firmware file and model for backup. Thanks.